# MS Graph : Get user roles and mobile phone

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Where does MS Graph get the user information from when I run "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/"? I have entered mobile phone in my profile in both Azure AD and Office 365, but it still wont show up when I run /me.

How do I get the Azure AD user´s role, after a successful Azure AD login? Must I have a Premium paying account to get it?

Answer (score 0):

I can use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=mobilePhone to get the mobile phone. 
Please have a try with it.

For how to get the Azure AD user's role, please refer to [List memberOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

You will get a response like this:
[image: List Role].

"Company Administrator" means the role of the user is Global Admin.

Comment: The mobile query returns "mobilePhone": null. When I run the /me/memberof it says ""Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

Comment: Where did you set the mobile phone? O365 portal? If you using Microsoft Graph Explorer to call /me/memberof, please make sure that you have configured the required permissions: Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All.

Comment: Ah okey! Now I get a list of directoryObjects - for example "Fashion Events" and "Online Marketing" etc. I have made a simple group on my free-account where I added myself. But I cannot find the group in the list. Is it really from Azure AD?
I added Mobile Phone on in my company Office 365 and but  not in my Azure AD (I don't seem have authority to add it). Though I added mobile phone on my personal Azure account and ran MS Graph Explorer with the account, and mobile returned null.

Comment: Please add a screenshot about where you set the mobile phone and another one about how you add a group. Thus I can do further research for you.